# How can I verify the text in a pop-up window through Selenium 2?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write an automated test that will set the boolean result to 'true' once the pop-up displaying 'The promotion was successfully executed' message is received.

```
<div class="appriseOuter" style="left: 551px; top: 100px; display: block;">
    <div class="appriseInner">
        The promotion was successfully executed
        <div class="aButtons">
            <button value="ok">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using an xpath value to see if the text was correct, but my test isn't proceeding past this point--could anyone clear up how to check the text correctly?

```
String promotion = wait.until(selenium_driver.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='appriseOverlay']/div[@class='appriseInner']"))).getText();

if(promotion.contains("The promotion successfully executed")) result = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a very simple typo... Your HTML code does not contain any `<div>` with class `appriseOverlay`. Try to correct your xpath to search for `appriseOuter` instead.

Comment: The `appriseOverlay` div was actually the parent of `appriseOuter` and I skipped right over that div. Thank you!